# ASP.NET MVC How to make that one method is executed only by one thread simultaneously?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a static method that is called from ActionResults method. The static method makes calls to update shared data from the database, so, I need that the static method can only be executed by every request, then It couldn't be executed again until the previous call has finished.

The method is like :

```
    public static class GeneralSettings
    {
      
        public static string GetSSCC(string precode, int totalDigitNumber)
        {
            //Call to database to update data 
            [...]


            return "something"
        }

         
    }
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: See Microsoft's  [Overview of synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives)

Comment: Note that unless the database is local to the same machine that runs the code and only one instance of the application is ever running, you cannot rely on synchronisation in the code itself to guarantee the consistency of your data. Instead the code and database should consider how to deal with multiple writers using an approach such as optimistic concurrency and update the code to handle such scenarios as appropriate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Comment: Thank you  I think these links can guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use lock or monitor to implement thread synchronization which allowed only one thread access a function/variables at one time. Refer below articles:

[Lock Article](https://www.javatpoint.com/c-sharp-thread-synchronization)

[c# Lock Article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1c8574/thread-synchronization/)

Comment: Thank you, I have seen these approach when the shared data are variables in memory, but also it could be used to synchronize methods for calling  database?

Comment: whatever you put inside lock ...another thread has to wait for first thread